# can't connect databse in my cpanel

Tags: php, mysqli, cpanel, namecheap

i already purchase a web hosting and a domaine to my portfolio,but the connection with the contact form and the database is not set on in my Cpanel,i m trying to test the connection by simple file .
i don t know whats the problem i guess "mysqli" is not set on ,i checked the connection information (user,pass...) they are correct,any suggestions ?

Sponsor hosting : namecheap.com

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'user1';
$pass = 'pass1';
$db = 'db1';




$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$db);


if($con)
{

    print 'CONNECTED';

}
else
{
     print 'NOT CONNECTED';
}

?>
```

Comment: You can use the [mysqli_connect_error](http://php.net/mysqli_connect_error) function to retrieve the error message.

Comment: @Ragnis Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'db1'

Comment: "database is not set on in my Cpanel" - What are you trying to test then?

Comment: connected* @ÁlvaroGonzález

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to debug and check what happened , use this :

```
else
{
     print 'NOT CONNECTED';
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

instead of :

```
else
{
     print 'NOT CONNECTED';
}
```

Comment: i try it out ,thats what pop out  ----> Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'db1'

Comment: go to your cpanel and check that `user` have access to `db1` database or not , the steps are like this : (1) make a database , (2) select that database and make a user for it .

Comment: i solve it man,i wasn't add the "Privileged Users" in my Cpanel ,much love man really appreciate your time